# Need to check more than 1 condition for a column in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table Test:

ID  Name
1   Imp
1   Critical
2   Imp
2   NA
3   NA
3   NAN

Now I want to make 3 query:

1st Need to find the ID which has Ony Imp but not critical:

Expected Output:

ID  Name
2   Imp
2   NA

2nd Need to find the ID which has Imp and Critical both

Expected output:

ID  Name
1   Imp
1   Critical

3rd Need to find the ID which dont have either Imp and critical both

Expected output:

3   NA
3   NAN

I tried:

```
  select * from test where name not in ('imp','critical')
```

But it give me ID 2 as well.

I tried to add IN and Not IN in my query but somehow it is not giving me correct output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the EXISTS and NOT EXISTS clauses as follows:

Table variable for testing conditions:

```
DECLARE @test TABLE (id INT, name VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @test VALUES (1, 'Imp'), (1, 'Critical'), (2, 'Imp'), (2, 'NA'), (3, 'NA'), (3, 'NAN')
```

Case 1 - EXISTS on one condition, and NOT EXISTS on the other.

```
SELECT * FROM @test t 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @test WHERE id = t.id AND name = 'Imp')
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @test WHERE id = t.id AND name = 'critical')
```

Returns

```
2   Imp
2   NA
```

Case 2 - EXISTS on both conditions

```
SELECT * FROM @test t 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @test WHERE id = t.id AND name = 'Imp')
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @test WHERE id = t.id AND name = 'critical')
```

Returns

```
1   Imp
1   Critical
```

Case 3 - NOT EXISTS on both conditions

```
SELECT * FROM @test t 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @test WHERE id = t.id AND name = 'Imp')
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @test WHERE id = t.id AND name = 'critical')
```

Returns

```
3   NA
3   NAN
```